# Closing the window with Close(x) button If I already fired Closing Event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have already set closing Event on window which display message if my validation goes wrong but I want to close window with X button on the top and he does the same thing showing my message how to avoid this and close window on X button, can I bypass Closing Event with this button I am not doing MVVM application?

Comment: Full stops, where are they?

Comment: They closed me because my question is not useful for community I can not ask for 6 months ?

Comment: Really i can open new account I just want to learn but they shut me down ?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use the `Closing` event to hook up some validation. This event fires whenever the window is about to close, whether by calling `Close()`, using the "X" close button or hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. This event can also be cancelled which would leave the window open.

For example:

```
class MyWindow : Window
{
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosing(e);

        e.Cancel = !IsValid(); // your validation code
    }
}
```

Comment: private void Dv_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e){ if(Valuta.HasErrors || Valuta==null){Valuta.OnDone(new Valuta.Done("Informations are not valid")); e.Cancel=true;} I rised my message event if Property has errors or if he has null value and then my message raised

Comment: I made error forgot to write `new Valuta.DoneEventArgs("myMessage");` instead of `new Valuta.Done("myMessage");`

Comment: question is about mvc apparently

Comment: @EliArbel ah ok. seems the op is confused about what he is even doing